# Creating regular expressions for input validation

Tags: regex, xpages

I want to do field validation to see if the value matches a pattern but am having trouble understanding the necessary regular expression.  Is there a tool where you can enter a pattern and have it tell you the regular expression that will match it?  Or is anyone willing to take a shot at the formula?

The patterns I need to match are (the capital letters are literal, 'a' is a character from A-Z or 0-9 and 'n' is a character from 0-9):
    Aaaaaannn
    Tnnnnnnnnnnnnn
    Snnnnn

Fortunately these are all in separate fields, but if anyone can tell me how to validate any of these patterns in the same field, that would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a poor definition of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a tool where you can enter a pattern and have it tell you the regular expression that will match it?

I use RegEx Buddy. It isn't free but very good. Will create the required source and help you build the regex. 
http://www.regexbuddy.com/

A free online version is:

http://www.regextester.com/

> (the capital letters are literal, 'a' is a character from A-Z or 0-9 and 'n' is a character from 0-9): Aaaaaannn Tnnnnnnnnnnnnn Snnnnn

```
A[A-Z,0-9]{5}[0-9]{3} T[0-9]{13} S[0-9]{5}
```

Probably a number of ways to write it though.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test any of these.

Separately:

```
/\AA[A-Z0-9]{5}\d{3}\z/
/\AT\d{14}\z/
/\AS\d{5}\z/
```

Together:

```
/\AA[A-Z0-9]{5}\d{3} T\d{14} S\d{5}\z/
```

Comment: By 'together' does he mean `/\A(?:pat1|pat2|pat3)\z/` ?

Answer (score 1):

On Sourceforge you will find [The Regulator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/regulator/) It is a Windows app that helped me a lot. And yes among the Query languages Regex are the beast, second only to advanced XPath.